# Is the product of two different characteristic functions also a characteristic function?

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Suppose that $\phi_{X}(t)$ and $\phi_{Y}(t)$ are characteristic functions of $X, Y$, respectively. Moreover, $X$ and $Y$ are NOT independent random variables. I want to know if $\phi_{X}(t)\cdot\phi_{Y}(t)$ also a characteristic function?

Comment: Here is a hint: characteristic functions are exactly those functions that only take the values 0 and 1.  If you multiply two characteristic functions together, what values can they take?  Where will the product equal 1?

Comment: @Aaron The term characteristic function  has  different meaning in Probability Theory. So your comment is not relevant to this question. Please see the tags in this question.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X',Y'$ be independent random variables such that $X$ and $X'$ have the same distribution and $Y$ and $Y'$ have the same distribution. (Such random variables always exist). Then the characteristic function of $X'+Y'$ is $\phi_X \phi_Y$. So the answer is YES.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have another question: why do **such random variables always exist**?

Comment: @MinguQIU We can always construct independent random variables with given distrbution  functions. This is based on the construction of product measures. For the most general result in this direction you can read Kolmogorov's Consistency Theorem (aka Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem ) in Wikipedia.

Comment: Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem ensures the existence of $X'$ and $Y'$, however, can it provide the independence between $X'$ and $Y'$?

Comment: Yes, we can instruct the random variables so that that  distribution is the product measure.

Answer (score 0):

$\phi_{X+Y}(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{it(X+Y)}) = \mathbb{E}(e^{itX} \cdot e^{itY}) = \{  
\text{independence} \} = \mathbb{E}(e^{itX}) \cdot \mathbb{E}(e^{itY}) = \phi_{X}(t) \cdot \phi_{Y}(t)$.

So if $X \perp Y \Rightarrow \phi_{X+Y}(t) = \phi_{X}(t) \cdot \phi_{Y}(t)$

Comment: It is not given  that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The point of this question is $\phi_X \phi_Y$ is a  characteristic function of some random  variable even if $X$ and $Y$ are  not independent.

Comment: And my answer proves, that it is true in case when $X \perp Y$. So I proved the special case.